# Allocating memory to 3D array

Tags: c, pointers

I know how to allocate memory to 2-D array but if the ptr is defined as `int *ptr[][100];`

Then how can I allocate memory for `ptr` ?

Comment: Memory for array variables is allocated automatically. If you wanted to manually allocate memory for `ptr` it would need to be a pointer, not an array. `ptr` here is actually a 2D array of pointers. It would help if you explained what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: `int *ptr[][100];` declares a 2-D array of `int*`, whose first dimension is not known. The only places it's allowed are as an extern variable or since C99 as a member of a `struct`. In the former case you *don't* allocate the memory for it, you link against a definition of it from some other source file. In the latter case you're using a "flexible array member", anything that explains to you what that is should also explain how to allocate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from section 6.2.5 of the C standard:

> An array type of unknown size is an incomplete type. It is completed,
>   for an identifier of that type, by specifying the size in a later
>   declaration (with internal or external linkage).

thus, to use `int *ptr[][100];` you have to link against a definition of it. If you specify that length then you have a 2D array of pointers to `int`. At this point you have to allocate a chunk of memory large enough for the 3D array, and assign correctly each `int *` in the 2D array.

A more straightforward approach could be the following:

```
int nx = 100;
int ny = 200;
int nz = 300;

int (*parray)[ny][nz] = malloc(nx*ny*nz*sizeof(int));
```

The last line allocate a pointer to an array of an array of int, that can be effectively used like a 3D array. For instance:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < nx; ii++)
  for (int jj = 0; jj < ny; jj++)
    for (int kk = 0; kk < nz; kk++)
      parray[ii][jj][kk] = ii*ny*nz + jj*nz + kk;
```

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12861532/771663) gives a really nice and precise overview of the use of pointers to array of types.

Answer (score 1):

Use `malloc` and specify the amount of bytes you need for the 3D array.

```
int *array3d = (int *)malloc(x * y * z * sizeof(int));
```

where x, y and z are the dimensions of your 3d array.

You can of course also have other types of array elements (float, chars, structs), just make sure you get the correct size using `sizeof`.

Comment: i guess you need to update int array3d. It's quite confusing. malloc returns a pointer, not an integer

Comment: `int* array3d = malloc(x * y * z * sizeof(int));` you forgot the asterisk.